# Can i ignore unique value when update record laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to ignore unique validation on update
I created Request file named "AskQuestionRequest" has rules :

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'=>'required|max:255|unique:questions',
            'body'=>'required',
        ];
    }
```

when I update body record i get The "title has already been taken."
anyone can help !

Comment: You can define what ID it should ignore, by passing a second parameter.

Comment: @Qirel but form where I can get the id of the question, I pass "AskQuestionRequest" to update method